# Magopay Unauthorized Error

Tags: php, error-handling, payment-gateway

https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk

While using above MangoPay SDK https://docs.mangopay.com/ .

I have passed correct Client Id & Password for Sandbox Account & running

> /mangopay2-php-sdk-master/vendor/mangopay/php-sdk-v2/demos/users_create.php

```
MangoPay\ResponseException Code: 401
-------------------------------

Message: Unauthorized
-------------------------------

Details: 
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Please provide more details. There is not enough here to help you

Comment: It's not showing any kind of Description in Details:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somehow you are using the live url instead of sandbox url.

In [this page](https://docs.mangopay.com/guide/response-codes) i see that there are 2 different urls, one for Production and one for sandbox.

Maybe this option helps?

`$api->Config->BaseUrl = 'https://api.sandbox.mangopay.com';`

Comment: Maybe you dont have access to create a user. Can you create a regular payment with test credit card?

Answer (score 0):

For previous credentials i don't have passphrase.

So i have created new Sandbox Credentials & It's working fine.

Thank you for your support :)